# Is it possible for gcc to order resulting binary differently?

Tags: gcc

The command `gcc -c a.c b.c c.c` produces a different binary than if the source files were ordered differently on the command line.  For security purposes, I'd like the binary ordering to change each time the file is built. Is there a built in option for gcc to do this?  or any better method than manually reordering the source files?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind it being *probabilistically different* then you could write a small shell script to randomize the inputs:

```
gcc -c $(ls *.c | sort --random-sort) -lwhatever
```

Of course, parsing `ls(1)` output in general is dangerous, but since these are your source files, show a little discretion in your names and avoid newlines.

The downside, of course, is that the same random order might result for multiple runs. Such is life.

Comment: If the order is the same, then they're no worse off than they are now.  The `--random-sort` option to `sort` is not necessarily available everywhere (Mac OS X, for example).  Also, `make` does not understand blanks or tabs in file names; if you're using `make`, you won't have file names that cause `ls` problems.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks, I hadn't realized `--random-sort` was a GNUism.